# How to use get prefix with method name in spring-data-solr?

Tags: java, spring, solr, spring-data-solr

There are lot of examples for findBy prefix but i couldn't find any example or document for how to use get prefix with method name to get the  all 'address' fields from solr. This is my Dao class

```
@Repository
public interface CarDao extends SolrCrudRepository<House,String> {

    Page<CarModel>findByNameContainsIgnoreCaseAndConditionAndCountry(String name,String condition,String country, Pageable pageable);


    List<String> getAddress();
}
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fields` attribute in `@Query` annotation on `getAddress` method to get the required fields.

```
@Query(fields={"address"}, value="YOUR_QUERY")
List<String> getAddress();
```